# With JQuery is $(this).find(e.target) the same as $(e.target, this)

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

[image: JQuery error?]

I've always thought it was until I got the above. Am I missing something?

The "input#header-login-email-input.initial-value" is not within "this".

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you showed some actual code.

Comment: Here's some code if you need some context `code`$("body").click(function (e) {
        $(".ui-tabs-handle-dropdown").filter(function () {
            return $(this).find(e.target).length ? false : true;
        }).tabsHandleDropdown("resetTabs");
    });`code`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume `e.target` is the target property of an `Event` object, so it's a DOM element. When you call `$()` on a DOM element, it just wraps the element in a jQuery object and returns that, so the context parameter (`this`) doesn't really do anything.

Comment: Ok. The context is ignored if you are passing in an element.